# convertir U+XXXX a hexadecimal utf8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, unicode

Me gustaría saber cómo convertir una cadena como esta: **U+1F601**  a este formato: **\xF0\x9F\x98\x81**

Podemos ver un ejemplo en esta página: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Ahí se especifica su código UNICODE y su valor en bytes.

Utilizo python 2.7

En esta web hace lo que yo quiero, pero no se cómo funciona internamente:
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=1F601&mode=hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `.encode()` de las cadenas Unicode de Python te permite especificar a qué codificación quieres convertirlo. En tu caso basta especificar `utf8`. Pero queda la cuestión de cómo meter un carácter unicode cualquiera (en tu caso el `U+1F601`) dentro de la cadena.

La forma de hacerlo depende del código del carácter.

- Si el código cabe en 8 bits, pones `\xHH`, siendo `HH` la representación hexadecimal de esos 8 bits. Fíjate que estamos hablando del código Unicode, no de su transformación a UTF-8. Así, por ejemplo, el código de la eñe es `U+00F1`, pero ya que la parte alta es 00, sólo necesitamos especificar el `F1`, que cabe en ocho bits, por lo que sería `\xf1`.

  Otra cosa es su representación utf8, que serían dos bytes y que podemos obtener con:

  ```
  >>> u'\xf1'.encode("utf8")
  b'\xc3\xb1'
  ```
- Si no cabe en 8 bits pero cabe en 16, como por ejemplo el código del euro (€) que es `U+20AC`, puedes usar la forma `\uXXXX`, donde `XXXX` es la representación hexadecimal de esos 16 bits. Su transformación a UTF8 se obtiene igual que antes:

  ```
  >>> u'\u20ac'.encode("utf8")
  b'\xe2\x82\xac'
  ```
- Finalmente, si tampoco cabe en 16 bits, como es el caso de los emojis y de tu ejemplo, entonces hay que representarlo con 32 bits usando la forma `\UXXXXXXXX`, siendo `XXXXXXXX` la representación hexadecimal de esos 32 bits. En tu ejemplo, `U+1F601` se representaría como `\U0001F601`. Para obtener los bytes de su codificación utf8, se hace igual que antes:

  ```
  >>> u'\U0001F601'.encode("utf8")
  b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'
  ```

Observa que la última opción es la más general de todas, ya que lo que cabe en 8 bits también cabe en 32. Por tanto sería posible representar la eñe como `\xf1` y tambien como `\U000000f1`.

**Actualización**. Si lo que tienes es una cadena del estilo `"U+XXXXX"` y quieres obtener la versión utf8 del caracter allí representado, no necesitas nada de lo anterior. Basta extraer lo que va detrás del `U+`, decodificarlo como un entero en hexadecimal, y usar `chr()` para obtener el carácter (unicode) que corresponde a ese código. Una vez tienes el carácter, usas `.encode("utf8")` para obtener su codificación. Así:

```
def unicode_to_utf8(unicode_point):
  code = int(unicode_point[2:], 16)
  return chr(code).encode("utf8")
```

Ejemplos:

```
>>> unicode_to_utf8("U+F1")
b'\xc3\xb1'
>>> unicode_to_utf8("U+20AC")
b'\xe2\x82\xac'
>>> unicode_to_utf8("U+1F601")
b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'
```